# date validation in java

Tags: java, date, jodatime

I need to validate a string to see whether it represents a ISO format date or not and if it doesn't i need to throw a user defined exception.

I have this line of code,

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = ISODateTimeFormat.date();
```

How do I use this formatter to validate the string?

Comment: Why throw a user-defined exception?  There is a DateFormatException built in to the existing date formatting libraries.  You could also throw another runtime exception like IllegalArgumentException.  Are you expecting to recover from the exception?

Comment: why don't you just use SimpleDateFormat: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html ?

Comment: @Foo Because an application-specific exception is often more useful than a lower-level exception.

Comment: @DaveNewton, could you provide an example specific to this case?  I don't  understand how IllegalArgumentException or DateFormatException could be improved on here.  Effective Java (Bloch) recommends reuse of the standard exceptions.  They are familiar, it promotes code reuse, and fewer classes must be loaded into memory.

Comment: @Foo I don't know the OP's case, so no, but in general: say this is buried in a service or in a type conversion process. It might be more beneficial to throw an app-specific exception from the service layer to aid in validation handling or declarative app exception handling. Re-using standard exceptions is fine in isolation, but when you're operating in the context of a larger application and/or framework, it doesn't always make sense.

Answer (score 1):

By trying to parse it with the [formatter.parseDateTime()](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#parseDateTime%28java.lang.String%29) method.

When the string is not a valid date, it will throw an IllegalArgumentException. When you want to throw your own exception, just catch it and throw another one.

Answer (score 0):

You can try parsing with the `formatter` that you've got, catch `IllegalArgumentException`, and throw user-defined exception instead:

```
try {
    formatter.parseMillis(stringBeingValidated); // You can use another parseXYZ method here
} catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
    throw new CustomException(iae.getMessage()); // The getMessage() call is only an example.
}
```